# How to resolve " 'IAsyncActionWithProgress<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced" in Windows UAP app

Tags: windows, async-await, windows-10

I am developing a Windows UAP app in Visual Studio Ultimate  CTP 2015 (latest one available in site).

I am facing issues while using await on Functions returning **IAsyncActionWithProgress<>, IAsyncAction<> , IAsyncOperation<> and IAsyncOperationWithProgress<>.**

I am getting the following error

**Error
CS0012
The type 'IAsyncActionWithProgress<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.**

I tried adding reference to the assembly mentioned (Windows). Even though this resolved the above error, it created another error at many other places (seems like there is a repetition of some classes/API's in both the assemblies. One of the error obtained is :

**Error
CS0433
The type 'Page' exists in both 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' and 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.**

Example of code

```
Windows.Storage.FileProperties.BasicProperties fileSize = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
```

This was working fine for a Windows Phone 8.1 app in Visual Studio 2013. 
What is the change I have to make to get the same result in UAP App in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: The project is a Windows 10 UAP project or is the previous version?

Comment: Its a Windows 10  UAP Project.

Comment: The exact same situation happened to me after VS update 3. Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with the IAsyncAction and I have just managed to solve it, so I am going to share the (maybe not the best) solution.

First I tried repair VS, no success. Then reinstalling VS, again no success. So I went to control panel -> programs -> uninstall programs, and from there I uninstalled everything that had something to do with Visual Studio or .NET. It displayed me a couple of errors, like that some applications require this program to run, but i anyway uninstalled it (if I will need it I will install it again). After that I installed Visual Studio again, wrote the code which caused the error and, it worked, with no error.

Hope this helps you as it did help me.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks Jakub. To flush it out a little more I:
1. Uninstalled VS 
2. Uninstalled all Windows SDK
3. Deleted C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
4. Reinstalled VS 2017 and allowed it to install my Windows SDK

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like your migration from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 didn't go through quite right. Andy Wigley has a video with instructions on how to migrate a Windows 8.1 project to Windows 10. His example is for Phone but also applies to desktop. Here's the video: http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/a-developers-guide-to-windows-10-preview. Go look at the section titled "Migrating 8.1 Apps to Windows 10".

To be clear, you shouldn't need to add any references to get those types working in a Windows 10 Universal App. A good starting point (on Andy also points out in his video) is to create a new black Windows 10 Universal App project and compare your project and package manifest files to it and just bring over the changes.

Comment: I actually didn't migrate from Windows 8.1 to UAP. I created a new project in UAP and Copied all my code into the new UAP project, so that I don't want to play with package manifest and other project related files

Comment: @JoseJohnThottungal My guess would be that your VS install got borked. I know it's a lot to ask but you might want to uninstall: Windows 10 Tools and Visual Studio 2015 (two separate things in the Add/Remove Programs applet in Control Panel). Then restart and reinstall. It is pre-release software so this sort of thing does happen unfortunately. 

Alternatively, wait till [Build](http://www.buildwindows.com) when the new SDK and tools drop before you do this. Again, sorry about your subpar experience with this :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the following, you can deploy on the Windows Phone but when you try to access to specific functions of the Phone you need to add
[image]

Comment: John Could you please put some more detailed code about the file you are using.

Comment: Can you give me the Version of Visual Studio You are using. I doubt that my Visual studio installation has not happen properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like changing `Project -> Properties -> Library -> Min version` from any version below `14393` to `14393` or above helps with the issue.

[image]

[image]