# Universal WIndows App Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, uwp, universal

When creating a Blank Universal Windows App, I am getting the following errors:

```
The type 'IAsyncAction' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.    
The type 'IAsyncActionWithProgress<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.  
The type 'IAsyncOperation<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.   
The type 'IAsyncOperationWithProgress<,>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Visual Studio 2015 setup failed at some point. This error should never happen.

Perform a clean install (unsinstall/re-install).

Here are some references

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2015/05/21/win10-apps-in-net-common-library-issues.aspx

[How to resolve " 'IAsyncActionWithProgress<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced" in Windows UAP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671811/how-to-resolve-iasyncactionwithprogress-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is)